# Specify "privileged" container mode in dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, bgp

I am a little new to Docker technology, however, I would like to deploy a couple of BGP BIRD containers throughout my infrastructure. I would like to automate container creation with Dockerfile builds, however, I can not run BIRD in docker without giving the container "privileged" mode. There doesn't appear to be a Dockerfile version for getting "privileged" mode. Are there workarounds or perhaps I am missing the point?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't give `privileged` mode in Dockerfile. You can only run by `--privileged` when start docker by command line. 
There is one other way, that you can try start you docker container via [Docker API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.35/)

And set request param for auto run with `privileged` mode.

As I know, normal case you need to run docker in `privileged` mode is you wanna run docker in docker. What BIRD container is ?

Comment: I would love to not use "privileged" mode, but BIRD software requires it and will not run without it. BIRD is used for BGP routing and is quite popular between network administrators.

Here is a sample project on github by someone using BIRD:
https://github.com/globocom/bird-routing

Comment: @A.Smith And you can't start container by you hand, it must be automatic ? In this case, I think create a tool start container by call Docker APi is possible

Comment: Yes I can, but then I have to involve bash scripts for my automation + i'd like to deploy other non BIRD containers using the same Dockerfile.

Comment: You can call Docker API with curl. I think you can add that curl command in your bash script file..

Comment: Could you give me a sample of that? For example, if I wanted to build ubuntu container with "privileged status.

Comment: @A.Smith here you can find example that how you can call docker api to creat container with curl https://docs.docker.com/develop/sdk/examples/

Comment: And here is params that you can set to curl command. Notice to `HostConfig` for set `Privileged` is `true`

Comment: @A.Smith Here is what you need. https://gist.github.com/dangminhtruong/5c95ebe220584d3e0429c05549b98175

Answer (score 0):

If for any reason you cannot give arguments in CLI and knowing that `--priviledged` is mostly full container capabilities

then try docker compose maybe:

```
cap_add:
    - ALL
```

or list them all

Answer (score -3):

it's a parameter you pass when you run the container `--privileged`